# editing autofollow with salesforce chatter

Tags: trigger, chatter

So I have this idea to add a field to Contacts, where they autofollow Users they are associated with. My Idea is to be able to have User A create Contact A, and Contact A to be associated with (And hence autofollowing) User A, B, and C.

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this/have any idea of where I should start doing this? I just can't figure out how to edit the Chatter code on an enterprise account, or add functionalities to the Chatter codebase.

Is this possible? Any ideas of where to start would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [Cloud Swarm](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GGRwEAO) do what you need?  Test it out and see if you can meet your requirements that way.  If not, it is an unmanaged package, so you can read through the code and see examples of how to create EntitySubscription records (chatter follows).  That should give you a good place to start anyway.

Comment: Cloud Swarm doesn't quite meet my needs, but I am playing around with it's code base, and I think it is perfectly adaptable for my needs.